Backing up with 'Timeshift', what does it save?
I am creating a backup using the 'Timeshift' application but I am confused as to what it is storing in the backup and what it isn't.https://github.com/linuxmint/timeshift/blob/master/README.md, it says

It is designed to protect only system files and settings. User files such as documents, pictures and music are excluded.

But after creating a backup, you can select the backup instance in the list and browse the files found withing the backup.  And clearly within the filesystem structure, I can browse to /home/myusername/Documents/ and all my other personal documents like music and folders I have created in my /home directory are there in 'Timeshifts' file browser.
If anyone knows for sure the whether the /home directories are included in the backups created by 'Timeshift', that would same me a lot of time and effort finding the answer to my question through experimentation.
Basically I want to know if I have a catastrophic disc failure or even want to transfer to a new machine, could I reinstall the version of Ubuntu I was using before the failure, install Timeshift, and then restore a Timeshift backup from my external drive and have all my installed software and my personal documents like Visual Studio code projects and music all magically back like nothing ever happened

does this itsFOSS article provide any re-assurance?
